# Getting trigger's changes after dml statement

Tags: trigger, dml, triggercontext

I'm trying to use object's fields updated in a trigger in the context where the DML statement is executed, however I'm not being able to get the new values assigned by the trigger.

I did the following tests executing anonymous code:

Trigger

```
trigger TriggerPOC on MyObject__c (before insert)
{
    for (MyObject__c myObj : Trigger.New)
    {
        myObj.Name = 'Yay!';
    }
}
```

Test code

```
MyObject__c objTest = new MyObject__c(Name='should be replaced');
system.debug(objTest.Name); // displays 'should be replaced'
insert objTest;
system.debug(objTest.Name); // displays 'should be replaced' (expected 'Yay!')
system.debug([SELECT name FROM MyObject__c WHERE Id=:objTest.Id].Name); // displays 'Yay!'
```

My objective is to use the 'Yay!' value after execute the DML statement, but I can't get it unless I run a query to retrieve it. I would like to avoid do the query.

Now my question is:

why the new values assigned in the trigger are not reflected in the DML statement context?

also, is there an easier way to get the new assigned values without running a query?

Comment: You will need to do the query to get the updated value.

Comment: A way to think of this is that the trigger is executing in a separate process (the database) compared to the code that initiates the insert (an app server). Only the ID value comes back from the database to the app server automatically. There could be hundreds of fields and automatically syncing all of them between the two processes is not part of the design, hence the need to explicitly query.

Comment: why not use an `after insert` trigger? Trigger.new will then have all of the fields inserted as well as formula fields available to you (though not parent or child relationship fields - those require querying)

Comment: @KeithC Do you have a source doc/article where I can read about the separate process that you mention? Your comment seems to be close to the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @JoseCarlos Perhaps there is a document but I don't know of one. What I described is what I infer from reading various things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a DML statement, only the record Id is returned. So after you've inserted `objTest` only the Id will come back as a result of the DML statement. Another query is a must if you want to retrieve other values from that record.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that only Id will come back from DML operation. However I'm curious what's the explanation behind that behavior, I was guessing that it has to do with different process contexts or something like that. I tried to find something about it in SFDC docs but I didn't have success.

Comment: I don't have that level of detail, perhaps for performance. It might be worthwhile posting another question on this.